# Why does WIFI get IP & DNS from public address instead of my local Windows Server 2012 network?

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, router, dns, ip

My home network is set up on a Windows server 2012 domain. My router assigns internal IP addresses through DHCP and the IP address of the DNS server inside my network. This setup works fine, except:

WIFI IP addresses of devices no longer are assigned local IP addresses but instead get assigned public addresses such as 65... and 207... Internet connection is there because the DNS server used are public DNS servers.

All my devices are Apple-based, except for the Windows 2012 server. I have one Windows 10 device running as a virtual device on my MAC Big Sur desktop. It is set to share the Internet connection with its host and it has its own local IP address which is assigned by my Windows DNS server.

As a temporary fix I have WIFI addresses on each of my devices using manual local IP addresses.

I use an ASUS router mesh system that has three mesh nodes. Because I use my own router instead of the builtin router on the RCN modem The RCN router is set in bridge mode and simply passes the internet connection to the ASUS router. The RCN modem and ASUS router are connected via a non-managed switch.

Why would devices inside my network get outside IP addresses and DNS addresses instead of getting the information from the Windows Server?

Comment: You should check in logs or in adapter properties what DHCP server is used by the Wifi adapter. Check if the correct DHCP server assigns the address. It can also be misconfigured statically set fallback address when DHCP does not assigns any address.

Comment: So you're saying the if the device cannot get the IP information from my local server for an unknown reason and there is no backup address provided, the adapter pulls the IP address from a public DNS server?

Comment: No, that's not how DHCP works. DNS is not involved in providing IP addresses to computers. You can configure your computer with a fallback address in case the DHCP server is not reachable.

Answer (score 0):

if your Asus router is setup as AccessPoint not router with it's own sub classes of IPs it may happen that that router than just lets ISP's dhcp to assign IP's, or alternatively your modem can possibly also assign public IP numbers as well.

1. check which DHCP assigned ip  (on win client)

   ifconfig /all

2.) check setting of this DHCP, that it actually assigns IP from it's own class.

btw, if you have computers in the same network that use both LAN and WiFi connections it makes sense to separate WiFi network to different subdomain (ie wired 192.168.1.0/24, wireless 192.168.2.0/24), as many win clients happily confuse routing tables when 2 eth cards are active within the same network, as it defines 2 default routes, or just keep one card at the time active.